# Where I can find online translation tool for .RC files?

Tags: translation, react-os

I checked few of online translation tools, but anyone have support for .RC files.

Example of file: http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/base/applications/mspaint/lang/en-US.rc?view=markup

Anyone have URL to translation tools which have support this format or any another idea to improve thanslation in ReactOS project?

Greetings,
Saibamen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SDL Trados Studio you can define your own filetypes. You can extract text with regex or you can actually build your own parser in C#.
Depends on the size of your project if this is overkill or not.

Is the format the same as the windows resource .rc files? If yes, you can convert them to .po files and then use POedit.
http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/stable-1.11.0/commands/index.html